# How can I call aggregate functions for properties of relationships in Realm?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Is there a way to use aggregate functions for properties in a one-to-one and one-to-many relationship? Here's a simple example of the structure I'm using:

```
class Toy: Object {
    dynamic var purchaseDate: NSDate?
    dynamic var name: String = ""
    let ratings = List<Rating>()
    dynamic var toyOwner: Person?
}

class Rating: Object {
    var stars: Int = 0
    var comments: String?
}

class Person: Object {
    dynamic var name: String = ""
    dynamic var age: Int = 0
}
```

I'd like to do something along the lines of this:

```
// Average age of owner of all toys purchased within a date range
let avgAge: Double = realm.objects(Toy)
    .filter("purchaseDate >= %@ && purchaseDate <= %@", startDate, endDate)
    .avg("person.age")

// Sum up all stars given to all toys purchased within a date range
let totalStars: Double = realm.objects(Toy)
    .filter("purchaseDate >= %@ && purchaseDate <= %@", startDate, endDate)
    .sum("sum(ratings.stars)")
```

Is there a way to do these aggregate functions within Realm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Realm does have aggregate value functions (See [Aggregate Operations](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Protocols/RealmCollectionType.html#/Aggregate%20Operations) docs on `RealmCollectionType`), those don't currently work with multi-level keypaths like `person.age`.

However, you can do most of the heavy lifting with Realm by slightly modifying your queries:

```
// Average age of owner of all toys purchased within a date range
let ages = realm.objects(Toy)
    .filter("purchaseDate BETWEEN %@", [startDate, endDate])
    .valueForKeyPath("toyOwner.age") as! [Double]
let avgAge = ages.reduce(0, combine: +) / Double(max(ages.count, 1))

// Sum up all stars given to all toys purchased within a date range
let totalStars = realm.objects(Toy)
    .filter("purchaseDate BETWEEN %@", [startDate, endDate])
    .reduce(0) { sum, toy in
        return sum + toy.ratings.sum("stars")
}
```

Comment: BETWEEN gives date `>` and `<` .. not `>=` and `<=` .. so what we can do to get date `<=  to >=`

Comment: Foundation's `NSDate`/`Date` is backed by a `double`, which means that you should very rarely, if ever, check for equality. Consider extending the range by adding/subtracting a precision factor to `startDate` and `endDate`.